"How can I get error messages in Russian for Python in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, as they are already in Russian for C++?"
When working with Python in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, error messages are displayed in English, while they appear in Russian for C++. I would like to configure Visual Studio so that error messages for Python are also displayed in Russian, similar to how they are for C++.
What you tried: I have checked the language settings in Visual Studio and ensured that the Russian language pack is installed. I verified that error messages for C++ are displayed in Russian, but Python error messages remain in English. I attempted to set the locale for Python within Visual Studio, but it did not change the error message language.
What you expected: I expected that configuring the Russian language settings in Visual Studio would also apply to Python error messages, displaying them in Russian as it does for C++.

To the best of my knowledge, it is not an option.

Why?...........

Python never got a Russian (or any other) localization - so, it is already impossible. But in addition to that, unlike C++ compiler being a part of VS, Python is an external tool that comes in a dozen different flavors (besides vanilla CPython, think of PyPY, Iron Python, etc). Making a consistent integration with VS would be (again, only in theory) somewhat cumbersome.
